# Web Crawler alternatives for Sparkler

Tags: data-visualization, web, scraping, dashboard, docker

There was a Web Crawler called [sparkler](https://github.com/USCDataScience/sparkler) but today is defunct.

I'm looking for an alternative that could:

- crawl the web and list top URLs with number of iterations
- have a dashboard that could show the big picture like sparkler [was doing](https://data-seo.com/2017/12/28/advanced-r-programming-seo-crawler/):

[image]

In alternative, if it doesn't comes with a dashboard it would be great at least to output the results to CSV and I will take care of that through Power BI.

But at least I need to save the output somewhere.

Everything points to [nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/) as an alternative but it really looks mediocre to me and I could not even pass the 4th installation step.